# How to solve this two error is 'changelangController.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback, object)'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

```
    protected override IAsyncResult BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        var langCookie = Request.Cookies["culture"];
        string lang;
        if (Request.Query.ContainsKey("lang"))
        {
            lang = Request.Query["lang"].ToString();
        }
        else if (langCookie != null)
        {
            lang = langCookie;
        }
        else
        {
            var userLanguage = HttpContext.Request.GetTypedHeaders().AcceptLanguage;
            var userLang = userLanguage?.FirstOrDefault()?.Value.ToString() ?? "";
            if (userLang != "")
            {
                lang = userLang;
            }
            else
            {
                lang = LanguageManage.GetDefaultLanguage();
            }
        }
        new LanguageManage().SetLanguage(lang);
        return base.BeginExecuteCore(callback, state);
    }
```

How to solve this two error is 'changelangController.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback, object)'and how to call redirect from function BeginExecuteCore to another controller.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What error exactly?